# Custom loop - Isolating post meta output depending on current query taxonomy terms

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop, meta-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have started constructing is a page to display a series of products based on certain criteria. Each product is part of two separate taxonomies, one for brand and one for product size (each product can come in a multitude of sizes). I have set up several meta image upload boxes on the post screen to allow a different thumbnail to be uploaded for each products size (packaging etc is different). How I want it to appear is in a list of sorts following a similar structure to:

```
Product Size 1
  -Brand 1
     -Product 1
        -Product 1 thumbnail for Product size 1
     -Product 2
  -Brand 2
     -Product 1
     -Product 2
  -Brand 3

Product Size 2
  -Brand 1
     -Product 1
        -Product 1 thumbnail for Product size 2
     -Product 2
  -Brand 2
     -Product 1
     -Product 2
  -Brand 3
```

I have managed to get the list itself displaying correctly but each post is displaying every thumbnail available, as opposed to the one in the current loop of the query.

Inside each post I have printed the output of the current product, which does display correctly for each one. However, when I run an `if` statement to check if the thumbnail exists, it displays them all. I'm hoping I have just overlooked something, though I can't see the wood for the trees at the moment.

I do still need to clean up the code a little, but hopefully it is easy enough to follow.

```
$beertax_terms = get_terms( 'beer_tax' );
foreach( $beertax_terms as $beertax_term ) {
    $currentproduct = $beertax_term; ?>
    <div class="beerproducts">
        <h3><?php echo ($beertax_term->name) ?></h3>
        <?php $beerbrewer_terms = get_terms( 'beer_brewery' );
        foreach ( $beerbrewer_terms as $beerbrewer_term ) { ?>
            <div class="beerbrewery">
                <h4><?php echo ($beerbrewer_term->name) ?></h4>
                <?php $beerargs = array (
                    'post_type' => 'beer',
                    'orderby'   => 'name',
                    'order'     => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'beer_tax',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => ($beertax_term->slug),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'beer_brewery',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => ($beerbrewer_term->slug),
                        ),
                    ),
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $beerargs );
                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        $cask = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'beer_caskthumb', true);
                        $keg = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'beer_kegthumb', true);
                        $bottle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'beer_bottlethumb', true); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark">
                            <div class="beer">
                                <?php the_title();
                                print_r ($currentproduct);
                                if ( $currentproduct->name = 'bottle' ) {
                                    ?><!--bottle--><?php 
                                    //if ( $bottle !='' ) {
                                        //echo $bottlethumb;
                                    //}
                                } 
                                if ( $currentproduct->name = 'cask' ) {
                                    ?><!--cask--><?php
                                    //if ($cask !='') {
                                        //echo $caskthumb;
                                    //}
                                } 
                                if ( $currentproduct->name = 'keg' ) {
                                    ?><!--keg--><?php
                                    //if ($keg !='') {
                                        //echo $kegthumb;
                                    //}
                                } ?>  
                            </div>
                        </a>                                                           
                <?php }
                wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <!--close beerbrewer-->
    </div>
<?php }
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort the problem out myself with a fresh set of eyes but thought it would be useful for others if they find themselves with a similar issue in future. If the answer needs tidying please feel free to suggest any edits.

I had to edit a few lines of code in order to resolve it but here is the complete block again.

Firstly I had to add in an additional variable to store the current product taxonomy term inside another variable by adding in the below inside of the post output.

```
$currentslug = $currentproduct->slug
```

I then proceeded to change the call

```
if ( $currentproduct->name = 'bottle' ) {
```

To this noting to add the double "=" (means `$currentslug` and `'bottle'` are equal) which meant the variable `$currentslug` would be checked and reset on each run through the loop instead of checking `$currentproduct->name` on the fly. Someone please correct me if I have misunderstood this but I'm assuming `$currentproduct->name` doesnt work because it hasn't been stored anywhere for use later in the loop?

```
<?php if ($currentslug == 'bottle') {
```

Which allowed me to identify the isolate the current taxonomy term to go in and add in an additional call to pull through the correct attachment thumbnail from the relevant meta field.

Which I did via

```
<?php 
 if (!empty($bottle)) {
        $attachment_id = $bottle[id];
    } else {
        $attachment_id = NULL;
    }
    $bottlethumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium' ); 
    echo $bottlethumb 
 ?>
```

And finally the working code (there are still a few bits I need to add in but the initial problem has been resolved).

```
    <?php $beertax_terms = get_terms( 'beer_tax' ); ?>
<?php foreach($beertax_terms as $beertax_term) { ?>
<?php $currentproduct = $beertax_term ?>
<div class="beerproducts">
    <h3><?php echo ($beertax_term->name) ?></h3>
        <?php $beerbrewer_terms = get_terms( 'beer_brewery' ); ?>
            <?php foreach($beerbrewer_terms as $beerbrewer_term) { ?>

                <div class="beerbrewery">
                <h4><?php echo ($beerbrewer_term->name) ?></h4>
                    <?php $beerargs = array (
                            'post_type' =>  'beer',
                            'orderby'   =>  'name',
                            'order'     =>  'ASC',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'beer_tax',
                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => ($beertax_term->slug),
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'beer_brewery',
                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => ($beerbrewer_term->slug),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ); ?>
                    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $beerargs ); ?>
                        <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) { ?>
                            <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) { ?>
                                <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                                <?php $cask = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'beer_caskthumb', true); ?>
                                <?php $keg = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'beer_kegthumb', true); ?>
                                <?php $bottle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'beer_bottlethumb', true); ?>
                                <?php $currentslug = $currentproduct->slug ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark">
                                        <div class="beer">

                                            <?php if ($currentslug == 'bottle') { ?>
                                                <!--bottle-->
                                                <?php if (!empty($bottle)) {
                                                            $attachment_id = $bottle[id];
                                                        } else {
                                                            $attachment_id = NULL;
                                                            }
                                                        $bottlethumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium' ); 
                                                        echo $bottlethumb ?>

                                            <?php } if ($currentslug == 'cask') { ?>
                                                <!--cask-->
                                                <?php if (!empty($bottle)) {
                                                            $attachment_id = $cask[id];
                                                        } else {
                                                            $attachment_id = NULL;
                                                            }
                                                        $caskthumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium' ); 
                                                        echo $caskthumb ?>

                                            <?php } if ($currentslug == 'keg') { ?>
                                                <!--keg-->
                                                <?php if (!empty($keg)) {
                                                            $attachment_id = $keg[id];
                                                        } else {
                                                            $attachment_id = NULL;
                                                            }
                                                        $kegthumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium' ); 
                                                        echo $kegthumb ?>
                                            <?php } ?>    

                                        </div>
                                    </a>

                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata();?>
                        <? } ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                <!--close beerbrewer-->
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<!--close beerproducts-->
</div>
<?php } ?>
```